# How to upload file via AJAX AND colorbox popup page

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, file-upload, colorbox

I'm a new programmer and stucked in a code.

I have a page called addstudents.php.. And I am showing this page in colorbox (popup).. This (addstudents.php) contains form to upload file in this way

> < form id="Form_upload" action="upload_pic.php" method="post"
>   enctype="multipart/form-data" > < table> < tbody> < tr> < td>< label
>   for="pic_source"     >Picture :    <    /label><   /td> < td><  input
>   type="file" class="data_input" size="60" name="pic_source"
>   id="pic_source" /> < /td>  < /tr   > < tr  > < td   >   Uplaod    <
>   /td   >  < td    >< input type='submit' value='proceed' id='submit'/
>
> > < /td   > < /tr   > < /tbody   > < /table   >  < /form    >
>
> Blockquote

the upload_pic.php is in the same folder as in addstudents.php is.And I want to store uploaded files in the samefolder too.
How can i upload the picture while not to close popup.. Please tell me and describe me the code.. Thankx in advance

Answer (score 0):

Submitting form will reload page. I guess you want to avoid that. 
I would use one of jQuery file upload plugins like this:
http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/
to do that.